# How to decrypt SSL/TLS traffic coming from genymotion

Tags: android, https

I have an app that makes get requests to a known address, but I don't  know what data is being sent or what urls are being requested.

The app is being run inside a genymotion virtual machine in a linux host.

It's written in flutter so snooping the files is very hard.

Is there a way I could force insecure http or decrypt whats coming out of it ?

Also I'm not very good with raw networking stuff :P

Answer (score 0):

You can route the SSL/TLS traffic through a TLS proxy like [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) to have it decrypted. PolarProxy will generate a PCAP file without the TLS layer.

You need to route the VM's TLS traffic via PolarProxy. You also need to install PolarProxy's root cert in the Android VM like this:

`Settings > Security > (Encryption & credentials) > Install from SD card`

*Full disclosure: We are the developers of PolarProxy. The only other free tool we know of that can decrypt TLS to a PCAP file is SSLsplit, which you are free to try as well of course ;)*

Comment: Thanks, I've been actually thinking of something like this. Will try as soon as I have time.